# If block for specific url .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cross-domain, access-control

I have little problem here

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

How can I apply this header only if requested url is mydomain.com/ajax/wigdet ?
(I can't do this outside htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_setenvif` for this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/ajax/wigdet AJAX

Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=AJAX
```